# Finding the indices of the values of one list in another list

Tags: python

I have two Python lists of integers: `x`, and `y`. All elements of `x` appear somewhere in `y`, and only once. For each element of `x`, I want to know the index of the corresponding value in `y`. I then want to set these indices to a list `z`.

The code below works as I have just described. However, it seems a little clumsy for a task which I suspect may have a more elegant solution in just a couple of lines or so. Therefore, my question is, what is the least number of lines in which the following code can be rewritten?

```
z = [0 for i in range(len(x))]
for i, j in enumerate(x):
    for k, l in enumerate(y):
        if j==l:
            z[i] = k
            break
```

Comment: Lists do have an `.index()` method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```
z = [y.index(i) for i in x]
```

Comment: That's the way to do it.

Comment: Note that while this may not be an issue in practice for small lists, this has quadratic behaviour and so will be slow for large ones.  (You wind up scanning `len(x)` times through `y`, when really you only need to do it once.)