# Find the indices at which any element of one list occurs in another

Tags: python, arrays, list, indexing, element

Take lists `haystack` and `needles`

```
haystack = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'V', 'd', 'e', 'X', 'f', 'V', 'g', 'h']
needles = ['V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
```

I need to generate a list of the indices at which any element of `needles` occurs in `haystack`. In this case those indices are 3, 6, and 8 thus

```
result = [3, 6, 8]
```

[This question I found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26569855/finding-the-indices-of-the-values-of-one-list-in-another-list) is very similar and was rather elegantly solved with

```
result = [haystack.index(i) for i in needles]
```

Unfortunately, this solution gives `ValueError: 'W' is not in list` in my case. This is because the difference here is that an element of `needles` may occur in `haystack` a number of times or not at all.

In other words, `haystack` may contain no needles or it may contain many.

Answer (score 23):

```
haystack = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'V', 'd', 'e', 'X', 'f', 'V', 'g', 'h']
needles = ['V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
st = set(needles)
print([i for i, e in enumerate(haystack) if e in st])
[3, 6, 8]
```

Even if you used `[haystack.index(i) for i in needles if i in  haystack]` it would **not** work as you have repeated elements.

Making `st = set(needles)` means we have a linear solution as set lookups are `0(1)` which for large input would be significantly more efficient.

Comment: definitely a better solution to put `needles` in a set. The hash table lookup definitely improves performance.

Comment: @Anzel, defo, obviously won't make much difference here but on a large dataset it would be significant.

Answer (score 4):

```
needles_set = set(needles)
print [i for i, val in enumerate(haystack) if val in needles_set]
```

Comment: How to find the indices where the needles_set is not found in haystack?

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like the following.

```
[Haystack.index(x) for x in needles if x in Haystack]
```

If x is not in `haystack` then `haystack.index(x)` will not be called and no error should be thrown.

Comment: won't actually work because  you would always get the first index of any repeated elements

Answer (score 0):

In addition to failing if your needle is not in the haystack, the index method will return only the first position of the element you're looking for, even if that element appears more than once (as in the `'V'` in your example).  You could just do this:

```
result = [idx for idx, val in enumerate(haystack) if val in needles]
```

The enumerate function produces a generator that yields tuples of values - the first being the index and the second being a value:

```
>>> print(list(enumerate(['a', 'b', 'c'])))
```

Just check if each value is in your needles list and add the index if it is.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not the most efficient way but you could do something like this:

```
result = []
i=0
while (i < len(haystack)):
    if (needles.count(haystack[i]) > 0):
        result.append(i)
    i+=1
```

Which will make result = [3, 6, 8]