# How do I find indexes of one list based on values of another list?

Tags: python

I'm trying to obtain indexes of one list based on elements of another list.

Let's say I have:

```
list1 = [1, 2]
list2 = [1, 2, 2, 3]
```

I want to obtain indexes of list2 that match elements from list1:

```
>>> [0, 1, 2]
```

Is there any one liner that can do it? Thank you for any suggestions.

EDIT:
Current multiple line solution:

```
list1 = [1, 2]
list2 = [1, 2, 2, 3]
matched = []

for i, e in enumerate(list1):
    for j, f in enumerate(list2):
        if e == f:
            matched.append(j)
```

```
>>> [0, 1, 2]
```

Comment: So how would you do this with more that one line?

Comment: I don't know that yet. I am open to any suggestions but one liner would be the best.

Comment: I'm sorry, but stackoverflow is not a code writing service. You should do some research for that and when you get stuck, that's the time to ask a specific question.

Comment: If you want a one liner, use a list comprehension, with the logic you would use with multiline solution.

Comment: "Code writing service" - that's why I wrote "any suggestions" like in which direction to go. I tried for some time and failed, that's why I asked.

Comment: It is all not intended to replace existing tutorials or documentation — so clearly you have some more studying to do.

Comment: I think you will not understand these one-liner solutions if you do not know how to write a "more than one line" code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find the indices at which any element of one list occurs in another](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29452735/6045800)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For relatively short lists, you can use a list comprehension:

```
>>> list1 = [1, 2]
>>> list2 = [1, 2, 2, 3]
>>> [i for i, l in enumerate(list2) if l in list1]
[0, 1, 2]
```

If your lists contain thousands of elements or more, you should consider using `numpy` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
>>> [i for i, x in enumerate(list2) if x in list1]
[0, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

how about something like this:

```
print([i for i in range(len(list2)) if list2[i] in list1])
```